# HTTP POST request inside scheduled Cloud Function is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Below is my scheduler where I am reading data from firebase database and updating data by calling `receiptValidationRequest(key, receiptData, date)` . Inside this function , I try to retrieve validation data from the response of HTTP call to apple, but its not working properly. Sometimes it works and a few data got updated. I am not sure why is this happening and what i am missing there.

```
exports.updateDatabaseScheduler = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 */3 * *').onRun(async context => {
console.log('scheduler started');
await ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
      var childData = childSnapshot.val();
      console.log(i++ + " : " +childSnapshot.key);
      receiptValidationRequest(childSnapshot.key, childData['ReceiptData'], myDate);
    });
});
 console.log('scheduler finished');
});
async function receiptValidationRequest(userID, receiptData, myDate){
let password = 'my password';

try{
    const data = JSON.stringify({
        'receipt-data': receiptData,
        'password' : password,
        'exclude-old-transactions': false
    });

    const options = {
        resolveWithFullResponse: true,
        // hostname: 'sandbox.itunes.apple.com',
        hostname: 'buy.itunes.apple.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/verifyReceipt',
        method: 'POST',
        json: true,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            // 'Content-Length': data.length
        }
    };


    const req =  await https.request(options,res => {
        myStatusCode[0] = res.statusCode;
        let expireDate = [];
        let transactionId = [];
        var trialPeriod = [];
        var body = '';

        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`);
        res.on('data', d => {
            body = body + d;
            // console.log("body : "+body);
        });
        res.on("end", () => {
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            let array = Object.keys(body);

            console.log("body : "+body);
            //parsing data here
            insertIntoDB(userID, expireDate, transactionId, trialPeriod, myDate);

        });
    });
    req.write(data);
    req.end();
}catch(e){
    req.on('error', (error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });
 }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to [return a promise that resolves when all of the asynchronous work is complete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions).  Without that, Cloud Functions doesn't know when it's safe to shut down the function.  What you have right now is a race condition - sometimes the work compeltes before Cloud Functions shuts down, but not always.

I suggest looking into another HTTP library that makes it easier to deal with promises, such as "request-promise".

Comment: Please correct me where I doing mistakes
await ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  var aaar = [];
     snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
       var childData = childSnapshot.val();
       var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   var abc = receiptValidationRequest(childSnapshot.key, childData['ReceiptData'], myDate);
        resolve(abc);
       })
       .then((value) =>{
        console.log("promise value : "+ value);
        return value;
       })
       .catch((err) =>{
        console.error("promise error : " + err);
       })
       
     });
 });

Answer (score 1):

`receiptValidationRequest` is an async functioN. You are not awaiting while calling in `forEach`. Also, use `for..of` or `promise.all` instead of `forEach` as `forEach` doesn't work with promises in loop.